# Android intent opens picture gallery, but not picture. Why?

Tags: java, android, gallery

I have a few pictures in my app, and I want to open them in the default viewer when the user taps on them. Here's my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/mypic.jpg");
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");

startActivity(intent);
```

The default viewer is indeed opened, but it shows its "home screen", showing all the folders and galleries. It doesn't display the selected picture.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I have a few pictures in my app`. In yiour app? Where? Please explain first where your images exactly reside.

Comment: `default viewer` ??? What is the default viewer?

Comment: @greenapps The images reside exactly in `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/` I am sure the paths that I'm using are correct and the images exist. The _default viewer_ is whichever the user has configured. It can be Gallery, QuickPic, or any other. The system should know wich one to use.

Comment: Well that is not in any way in your app is it?

Comment: @greenapps Well, yes and no. The images are resources within my app, but I haven't been able to open them directly in an external viewer; so, I saved them as files. Using the code above I am able to invoke a viewer, but it doesn't display the image, just  the "home screen", as if I had opened it freshly new from the applications menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With following code placed in a try block you can open any file:
Add the catch blocks your self.

```
             String FileName = ...full path of file...

             MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
             String extension = map.getFileExtensionFromUrl(FileName.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "")); // does not work with spaces in filename

             String mimetype = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

            Toast.makeText(context, FileName + "\nMimeType: " + mimetype + "\nExtension: " + extension , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if ( mimetype == null )
                {
                mimetype = "text/plain";
                Toast.makeText(context, "MimeType: " + mimetype, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            String Url = "file://" + FileName;

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(Url), mimetype);    
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Mmmmm i had not looked at your code too much and suddenly i see that you have about the same. The only problem with your code is that you use both setData() and setType(). setTyp() however will undo the data set by setData(). So that's why it did not work.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, sir. The order of `setType()` and `setData()`, and their separate use instead of `setDataAndType()` affects the result in great manner.